# Better way to map native query result set with spring data-jpa

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

If we need to map native sql resultset in Spring data. We need to create below `NamedNativeQuery`. It works well but if we have long/many queries its difficult to maintain here.

**is there any other way to achieve this?**

```
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery;
    import javax.persistence.Table;


        @Entity
        @NamedNativeQuery(name = "Todo.findByTitleIs”,
                query="SELECT * FROM todos t WHERE t.title = 'title'",
                resultSetMapping= "mapper"
        )
       @SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "mapper",
        classes = @ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = TodoDTO.class,
                columns = {
                        ..,

                }))
        @Table(name = "todos")
        final class Todo {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of JPA and Hibernate and other similar frameworks is not to write native query, then open a connection and so on and so on...
All of that is boiled down to a single method...
What I would suggest is to use the

```
pulblic interface JpaRepository<Todo, (the type of the Todo Id) >{

Optional<List<Todo>> findAllByTitle(String title);
}
```

The JpaRepository has many advantages, take a look into the matter :)
Hope this helps...

Comment: well above namedQuery gets called from spring data repository but when using `SqlResultSetMapping` for `Native` query you can not use directly in repository.

Comment: But the point is not to use the Native query, but use a Hibernate implementation.

Comment: As i said in these cases we prefer native queries.  These are mainly for reporting where we have complex queries